# File Path Name or URL analysis

Tags: machine-learning

I am looking for information on tools, methods, techniques for analysis of file path names. I am not talking file size, read/write times, or file types, but analysis of the path or URL it self.

I am only aware of basic word frequency text tools or methods, but I am wondering if there is something more advanced that people use/apply to this to try and mine extra information out of them.

Thanks!

UPDATE:

Here is the most narrow example of what I would want. OK, so I have some full path names as strings like this:

```
F:\Task_Order_Projects\TO_01_NYS\Models\MapShedMaps\Random_File1.doc
F:\Task_Order_Projects\TO_01_NYS\Models\MapShedMaps\Random_File2.doc
F:\Task_Order_Projects\TO_01_NYS\Models\MapShedMaps\Random_File3.doc
F:\Task_Order_Projects\TO_01_NYS\Models\MapShedMaps\Random_File4.doc
F:\Task_Order_Projects\TO_01_NYS\Models\MapShedMaps\Random_File5.doc

F:\Task_Order_Projects\TO_02_NYS\Models\MapShedMaps\Random_File1.doc
F:\Task_Order_Projects\TO_02_NYS\Models\MapShedMaps\Random_File2.doc
F:\Task_Order_Projects\TO_02_NYS\Models\MapShedMaps\Random_File3.doc
F:\Task_Order_Projects\TO_02_NYS\Models\MapShedMaps\Random_File4.doc
F:\Task_Order_Projects\TO_02_NYS\Models\MapShedMaps\Random_File5.doc
```

What I want to know is that the folder MapShedMaps appears "uniquely" 2 times. If I do frequency on the strings I would get 10 appearances. The issues is that I don’t know what level in the directory this is important, so I would like a unique count at each level of the directory based on what I am describing.

Comment: Can you give an example of the type of information you want to glean from the URL? You may try to look for tools for examining URI information. URL is actually a subset of URI and could be limiting you from tools out there. This guy explains it if your interested. http://www.bernzilla.com/item.php?id=100

Comment: Sure, ideally I'd like to see realtionships between high frequency names and their parent directories. So say a high number of paths end with "cost model," I'd like to know if there is a partern in the parent structure that would indicade a high likleyhood of a "cost model" name being used.

Comment: Do you have a preferred language that your trying to work in? Or are you just looking for generic means of achieving this?

Comment: I am looking for anything, even terms for this. Right now my searches are turning up mostly file forensic stuff, but I am really looking more for a text analysis tool. If it's PowerShell or .NET then I can work with that right away, but anything on methods, terms, techniques to help with more searching would be great.

Answer (score 2):

This is an extremely broad question so it is difficult for me to give you a per say "Answer" but I will give you my first thoughts on this.

First,

the Regular expression class of .NET is extremely useful for parsing large amounts of information. It is so powerful that it will easily confuse the impatient, however once mastered it can be used across text editors, .NET and pretty much any other respectable language I believe. This would allow you to search strings and separate it into directories. This could be overkill depending on how you use it, but its a thought. [Here is a favorite link of mine to try out some regular expressions.](http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm)

Second,

You will need a database, I prefer to use SQL. Look into how to connect to databases and create databases. With this database you can store all the fields abstracted from your original path entered. Such as a parent directory, child directory, common file types accessed. Just have a field for each one of these and through queries you can form a hypothesis as to redundancy.

Third,

I don't know if its easily accessible but you might look into whether windows stores accessed file history. It seems to have some inkling as to which files have been opened in the past. So there may be a resource in windows which already stores much of the information you would be storing in your database. If you could find a way to access this information. Parse it with regular expressions and resubmit it to the database of your application. You could control the WORLD! j/k... You could get a pretty good prediction as to user access patterns though.

Fourth,

I always try to stick with what I have available. If .NET is sitting in front of you, hammer away at what your trying to do. If you reach a wall. At least your making forward progress. In today's motion towards object orientated programming, you can usually change data collected by one program into an acceptable format for another. You just gotta dig a little.

Oh and btw, [Coursera.com](https://www.coursera.org/courses) is actually doing a free class on machine learning and algorithms. You might want to check it out or reference it for prediction formulas.

Good Luck.

Comment: Thanks, that is a good start. I was really hoping someone had tackled the issue of parsing URLs/path names before to do better frequency analysis. My common frequency methods are very innifcient because of the redundancy of folders in path names. It gets tricky to figure out what are unique namming patterns when a folder with 100 items will show higher frequnecy than 10 unique folders with 1 file in each. The later being what would be most useful.

Comment: Yeah I understand. .Net does distinguish between files and folders though through the Directoryinfo.getdirectories or directoryinfo.getfiles methods. These could be very helpful in determining the association between the two situations you explain above. It even has properties to determine the last time they were accessed. Check it out on MSDN help.

Comment: I guarantee if you narrowed your question down a bit then you would have a better chance at finding the answer your looking for.

Comment: updated my post with the best example of something that would help me.

Comment: Oh this is definitly a call for some juicy regex... I'll post back if I can get one specifically but I think you should start researching them. There are methods for you to define an expression that will match the directory, then and only then will it look for another match if the match is not found the record is unique otherwise regex discovers concurrency and does not add it to a unique list.

Comment: I was hoping this could be done without a DB and through a script, I'll read up. Also make sure to post and answer so I can vote it up.

Comment: Hey I just wanted to let you know I've been playing with some regex... I know a pretty easy way to code this up in VB.net and I'll post that as my second answer but I wanted you to check out backrefences. If the part between parenthesis matches it captures that text and moves on to the second query for instance.... F:\\(directory1)?(directory2)?(directory3)? You could use these matches to find out how many directories each parent directory has under it. Are you following me? Here is a reference. http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html (btw \ is an escape character for regex)

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to post this as a comment but SO kept editing the double \ to \ and it is important there are two because \ is a key character, without another \ to escape it, regex will interpret it as a command.

Hey I just wanted to let you know I've been playing with some regex... I know a pretty easy way to code this up in VB.net and I'll post that as my second answer but I wanted you to check out back-references. If the part between parenthesis matches it captures that text and moves on to the second query for instance....

```
F:\\(directory1)?(directory2)?(directory3)?
```

You could use these matches to find out how many directories each parent directory has under it. Are you following me? [Here is a reference.](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)